# Spring Data JPA Lazy loads collections annotated as Eager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a project that is using Spring Data repositories to auto generate some of its methods. One such method is one that accepts a couple parameters and returns a list of books. In the repository, that method looks like this:

```
List<Book> findBySellerFlagTrueAndPublishedState(PublishedState state);
```

However, when I use that method, it seems like hibernate is lazy loading properties of the books which are annotated as FetchType.EAGER. Also, I have the same issue when I build the query myself using JPA's Criteriabuilder. When I use the default `findOne(Long id)` method, those properties are eagerly loaded.

I'm using JPA 2.0, and am using Hibernate as the implementation.

Here's my annotations on one of the relationships I'm having this issue with:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="BOOK_THEME", 
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="BOOK_ID", referencedColumnName="BOOK_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="THEME_ID", referencedColumnName="THEME_ID"))
@OrderColumn(name="THEME_SEQUENCE")
private List<Theme> themes;
```

The getters and setters are just standard, and it's a unidirectional relationship (there are no books in `Theme`).

I think it must be an issue with how I have my annotations set up. Does anyone know what I have wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that annotating the themes with `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` accomplished my goals, but a better solution was to set `hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size` in the hibernate properties. That way I could set it to some number (I chose 100) and it would improve the performance of all lazy and eager fetching for many relationships at once.